# How to check if a column is null based on value of another column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I make my condition print True is if the `vin` at the specific `date_stamp` is null?

| vin | vinar | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | eqr21144 | 02-02-2021 |
| Ebntyure43 | Evirter45 | 02-03-2021 |

```
date_stamp = "02-02-2021"

df2 = df.withColumn(vin,F.when(F.col('date')==F.lit(date_stamp)).isnull())
if df2==True:
   print('True')
else:
   print('False')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot test whether a dataframe is true or false. You need to test the column, and collect the result using `head()[0]`:

```
result = df.filter(F.col('date')==F.lit(date_stamp)).select(F.col('vin').isNull()).head()[0]
```

then you can test the `result` using something like `if result: print('True')`

Answer (score 1):

You can also write it like this :

```
df2 = df.filter("date = '02-02-2021' AND vin IS NULL")

if df2.count():
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

If `df2.count > 0` it means there is at least one null value in `vin` for that date `date = 02-02-2021`